# Google Chrome Network Status Issues

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, networking, status

Anybody can help me please. My site pages are working in chrome console with status 200 ok. But when I go to chrome Network area and record my site activity it gives status 200 ok suppose when I try to click on my site online user page which is showing in the screenshot I get the Bug on this page which is also showing in the screenshot. My user online routes are I also tried to post method in the route command but error is the same. I'm getting this error on all my pages but my routes are all correct.

[image]
[image]

// Set Online Status

```php
Route::put('online', 'ProfileController@setOnline')->name('setOnline');
```

Comment: A click on a link makes a GET request. Your route is for PUT requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change request method of your route from put to get and do change the corresponding functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

as you can see from error it says method not allowed

```php
Route::get('online', 'ProfileController@setOnline')->name('setOnline');
```

Answer (score -1):

after change the put method to get method

Route::get('online', 'ProfileController@setOnline')->name('setOnline');

I get the error in the console and console network  error 422 .check screenshots please [image: error code is 422 after get method][image: after click on online link in the console network i get this error access denied 403]

What i should do now dear boss?????